Find if one value contains another
I am hoping to update VBA code to check if one cell (ex. A1) contains the text from another cell (ex. B2) then return a corresponding value.
The original code checks if the cells match.
Option Explicit
Function LookupCSVResults(lookupValue As Variant, lookupRange As Range, resultsRange As Range) As String

    Dim s As String 'Results placeholder
    Dim sTmp As String  'Cell value placeholder
    Dim r As Long   'Row
    Dim c As Long   'Column
    Const strDelimiter = "|||"  'Makes InStr more robust

    s = strDelimiter
    For r = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count
            If lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value = lookupValue Then
 
                sTmp = resultsRange.Offset(r - 1, c - 1).Cells(1, 1).Value
                If InStr(1, s, strDelimiter & sTmp & strDelimiter) = 0 Then
                    s = s & sTmp & strDelimiter
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    s = Replace(s, strDelimiter, ",")
    If Left(s, 1) = "," Then s = Mid(s, 2)
    If Right(s, 1) = "," Then s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    LookupCSVResults = s

What I am trying to accomplish:

If the "Companies" column in the original table contains the company listed in the new table, return the corresponding name in the original table to the "Employees" column in the new table.
I tried InStr.
Option Explicit
Function LookupCSVResults2(lookupValue As Variant, lookupRange As Range, resultsRange As Range) As String

    Dim s As String 'Results placeholder
    Dim sTmp As String  'Cell value placeholder
    Dim r As Long   'Row
    Dim c As Long   'Column
    Const strDelimiter = "|||"  'Makes InStr more robust

    s = strDelimiter
    For r = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count
            If InStr(lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value, lookupValue) > 0 Then
                sTmp = resultsRange.Offset(r - 1, c - 1).Cells(1, 1).Value
                If InStr(1, s, strDelimiter & sTmp & strDelimiter) = 0 Then
                    s = s & sTmp & strDelimiter
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Now make it look like CSV
    s = Replace(s, strDelimiter, ",")
    If Left(s, 1) = "," Then s = Mid(s, 2)
    If Right(s, 1) = "," Then s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    LookupCSVResults = s 

End Function


It looks like your file may be pipe (|} delimited - your strDelimiter has three pipe characters in it.  Also InStr returns the position if string is found else zero - should your comparison be > instead of =?

"then return a corresponding value" - it would help to explain exactly what this means.  Since your code does not work we can't figure it out from that...

Hi Ted, thanks for commenting - I've updated the post with sample data to help show the outcome I am looking for.

In ColD are items always on separate lines?

You can do this without VBA, using formulas.
For ease of set-up, create a name for the range shown below in green. I called it OriginalTable.

Then, you can create the first column of your new table by entering into cell F3 the formula:
=UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),FALSE,INDEX(originaltable,,2)),,CHAR(10),TRUE))
And the second column by copying down the formula in cell G3 and down:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(F3,INDEX(originaltable,,2))),INDEX(originaltable,,1),""))
Result:

